# FLUTTER: Bearer token not sending to the API

Tags: http, flutter, dart

Here is my code:

```
  var url = 'http://myURL';

  String tokens = "good token working on postman";

  var response = await http.get(url, headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $tokens',
  });

  print('Token : ${tokens}');
  print(response.body);
```

The problem is that the token and the api url is working well on PostMan but it looks like flutter doesn't send the token. 
It returns me a web page content.

Comment: use dio package, it has more advanced features, especially the interceptors

Comment: Make sure that your server accepts lower case header names - in this case `authorization`, as Dart will lower case them. This fools some servers that aren't RFC compliant.

Comment: @MuratAslan Thanks, tried with dio but same problem :'(

Comment: @RichardHeap Any idea how I can do this on symfony please?

Comment: try using [alt_http](https://pub.dev/packages/alt_http) instead of dart's http, it is used to respects case sensitive headers that's the dart's doesn't do.

Comment: Confirm whether it works when you set the header to lower case in Postman. If it fails, it's a server bug. If it works, it's something else.

Comment: @RichardHeap It worked in Postman with "authorization" so it's probably coming from flutter

Comment: Since your URL is `http` you should grab a packet capture. Also, in the above code you provide a content type - but no actual content! When diagnosing this type of issue it's often easier to just write a Dart command line program - but that does mean you need to also download the Dart SDK separately from the one included in Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.32:8000/api/users'), headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sharedPreferences.getString("access_token"),
    });
```

Comment: please mention what has been changed in the code and mention that particular piece in your code.